# Символы в названии объектов в Java

Tags: java

Объекты в Java могут именоваться со знака подчеркивания, знака доллара и букв. Именование запрещено с цифр, зарезервированными и ключевыми словами и литералами.

Вопрос:Все ли я назвал? И где конкретно можно это уточнить(В документации не нашел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описание идентификаторов есть в спецификации языка [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

```
Identifier:
    IdentifierChars за исключением ключевых слов, логических литералов или null

IdentifierChars:
    JavaLetter {JavaLetterOrDigit}

JavaLetter:
    любая литера из Юникод для которой Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int) ввернет истину

JavaLetterOrDigit:
    любая литера из Юникод для которой Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) ввернет истину
```

Comment: `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart` и `Character.isJavaIdentifierPart` - это ну просто шикарная расшифровка. Первым может быть любой, который может быть первым, а остальными - любой, который может быть частью.

Comment: @Qwertiy К сожалению я не знаю как описать эти символы по другому. Если у вас есть предложение, то я с удовольствием дополню ответ.

Comment: Вторые, вероятно, отличаются наличием цифр. А первые - любая юникодная буква и что там с долларом. Наверное. Не знаю. Где-то должно быть написано.

Comment: Не, не только. Там ещё куча всего.

Comment: Например, все эти литеры годятся для начала идентификатора _ ¢ £ ¤ ¥ ؋ ৲ ৳ ৻ ૱ ௹ ฿ ៛ ‿ ⁀ ⁔ ₠ ₡ ₢ ₣ ₤ ₥ ₦ ₧ ₨ ₩ ₪ ₫ € ₭ ₮ ₯ ₰ ₱ ₲ ₳ ₴ ₵ ₶ ₷ ₸ ₹ ꠸ ﷼ ︳ ︴ ﹍ ﹎ ﹏ ﹩ ＄ ＿ ￠ ￡ ￥ ￦

Comment: С первым я уже разобрался, а вот с остальными что-то не получается.

Answer (score 3):

http://ideone.com/oeGSHf

Первым символом может быть любая юникодная буква, а также следующие символы (сначала записан десятичный код, затем через тире сам символ):

```
36 - $
95 - _
162 - ¢
163 - £
164 - ¤
165 - ¥
1423 - ֏
1547 - ؋
2546 - ৲
2547 - ৳
2555 - ৻
2801 - ૱
3065 - ௹
3647 - ฿
5870 - ᛮ
5871 - ᛯ
5872 - ᛰ
6107 - ៛
8255 - ‿
8256 - ⁀
8276 - ⁔
8352 - ₠
8353 - ₡
8354 - ₢
8355 - ₣
8356 - ₤
8357 - ₥
8358 - ₦
8359 - ₧
8360 - ₨
8361 - ₩
8362 - ₪
8363 - ₫
8364 - €
8365 - ₭
8366 - ₮
8367 - ₯
8368 - ₰
8369 - ₱
8370 - ₲
8371 - ₳
8372 - ₴
8373 - ₵
8374 - ₶
8375 - ₷
8376 - ₸
8377 - ₹
8378 - ₺
8544 - Ⅰ
8545 - Ⅱ
8546 - Ⅲ
8547 - Ⅳ
8548 - Ⅴ
8549 - Ⅵ
8550 - Ⅶ
8551 - Ⅷ
8552 - Ⅸ
8553 - Ⅹ
8554 - Ⅺ
8555 - Ⅻ
8556 - Ⅼ
8557 - Ⅽ
8558 - Ⅾ
8559 - Ⅿ
8560 - ⅰ
8561 - ⅱ
8562 - ⅲ
8563 - ⅳ
8564 - ⅴ
8565 - ⅵ
8566 - ⅶ
8567 - ⅷ
8568 - ⅸ
8569 - ⅹ
8570 - ⅺ
8571 - ⅻ
8572 - ⅼ
8573 - ⅽ
8574 - ⅾ
8575 - ⅿ
8576 - ↀ
8577 - ↁ
8578 - ↂ
8581 - ↅ
8582 - ↆ
8583 - ↇ
8584 - ↈ
12295 - 〇
12321 - 〡
12322 - 〢
12323 - 〣
12324 - 〤
12325 - 〥
12326 - 〦
12327 - 〧
12328 - 〨
12329 - 〩
12344 - 〸
12345 - 〹
12346 - 〺
42726 - ꛦ
42727 - ꛧ
42728 - ꛨ
42729 - ꛩ
42730 - ꛪ
42731 - ꛫ
42732 - ꛬ
42733 - ꛭ
42734 - ꛮ
42735 - ꛯ
43064 - ꠸
65020 - ﷼
65075 - ︳
65076 - ︴
65101 - ﹍
65102 - ﹎
65103 - ﹏
65129 - ﹩
65284 - ＄
65343 - ＿
65504 - ￠
65505 - ￡
65509 - ￥
65510 - ￦
```